# How to ensure that webclient process error like they process 200

Tags: .net, webclient

I asked a similar question there but for curl and webclient.

I found the answer for curl:

[How to ensure that webclient/curl process 503 error like they process 200](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9062089/how-to-ensure-that-webclient-curl-process-503-error-like-they-process-200)

CURLOPT_FAILONERROR

I want something like that but for webclient rather than for curl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way each question is asked, probably means this question is a duplicate of the one linked to in this question. In any case I provide the same answer here as I did there:

For `WebClient` you need to process the `WebException.Response`. E.g. this LINQPad query dumps the HTML provided by my web server's "Not Found" error web page:

```
Dim wc = New System.Net.WebClient
Try 
  Dim rd = wc.DownloadData(New Uri("http://localhost/test"))
  rd.Dump
Catch Ex As System.Net.WebException
 Dim rs = Ex.Response
 Call (New StreamReader(rs.GetResponseStream)).ReadToEnd.Dump
End Try
```

Comment: Will that rd.Dump be executed when things go wrong? Or will it go exception straight?

Comment: Wherre can I see the documentation of this dump thingy? I don't see it Dump

Comment: For this purpose, `Dump` is just LINQPad's equivalent of `Console.WriteLine`, but just more formatted.

Comment: (Answering your first comment) No, the exception is thrown within the `DownloadData`, so the stream needs to be processed in the `Catch`.

Comment: I see. Is LinqPad from microsoft?

Comment: Can we do this without linqpad? Oh I see. you just dump the stuff to console. Nevermind. Yes I am supposed to put that on a variable.